# imageViewUIs image returns nill

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am using swift 2 and having a strange problem while following a tutorial to select image with picker and then apply a filter on pressing a button.

My process is something like this:

1. Click a button to use imagePickerControl to select image which
   displays it in image view's image
2. Click a button to process a filter
   on that image

This is the code of the image picker:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        if let pickedImage = image as? UIImage {
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This part does the processing/filtering:

```
func setProcessFilter() {
        var originalImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image!)
        if originalImage !== nil {
            var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectProcess")
            filter?.setDefaults()
            filter?.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            var imageOutput = filter!.outputImage
            var newImage = UIImage(CIImage: imageOutput!)
            imageView.image = newImage
        } else {
            print("problem!")
        }
    }
```

Interestingly this works the first time the button is clicked, however the second time originalImage becomes nill. I am not sure why this is happening?

[Here is my full code](https://github.com/kkarimi/poormans-instagram/blob/master/PoormansInstagram/ViewController.swift).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue while following tutorials, just create a var:

```
var filterImage : CIImage!
```

and once imagepicker has selected the image, push it to there:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    if let pickedImage = image as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        filterImage = CIImage(image: pickedImage)
        imageView.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```